# STM32 for loop slows down code too much

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, c, optimization

I am using an STM32 STM32F103C8T6 running at 48 MHz using ADC DMA and I find that using a `for` loop for manipulating arrays is much slower than multiple lines of code.

For example:

```cpp
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  int i = 0;
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 1u);

  for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    adc_read[i] = adc_buffer[i];
  }

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 0u);
}
```

vs:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 1u);

  adc_read[0] = adc_buffer[0];
  adc_read[1] = adc_buffer[1];
  adc_read[2] = adc_buffer[2];
  adc_read[3] = adc_buffer[3];
  adc_read[4] = adc_buffer[4];
  adc_read[5] = adc_buffer[5];
  adc_read[6] = adc_buffer[6];
  adc_read[7] = adc_buffer[7];
  adc_read[8] = adc_buffer[8];
  adc_read[9] = adc_buffer[9];
  adc_read[10] = adc_buffer[10];

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 0u);
 }
```

The `for` loop takes 7.9 μs while the direct assignment takes 3.58 μs when seen on an oscilloscope.

The GPIO state change takes 1.26 μs, so effectively the `for` loop takes 6.64 μs while direct assignment takes 2.32 μs to execute (almost 1/3).

Is there any way to speed up the `for` loop? For my final program I'd like to add the values to a variable which is then averaged to give me a filtered output.

-----------------EDIT-1-------------------------

Personal note - Also if the question doesn't make it clear, I am more of a hardware guy than a software guy. I expected the for loop to be about 10, 20 or 30% slower, never thought it could be 3x slower. I may never use for again :D.

All data is int 16 bits.

Assembly code as below.

```
08000246:   bl      0x8002c96 <HAL_GPIO_TogglePin>
0800024a:   movs    r3, #0
0800024c:   str     r3, [r7, #12]
 61           for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)  // starts here
0800024e:   movs    r3, #0
08000250:   str     r3, [r7, #12]
08000252:   b.n     0x800026a <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+54>
 64              adc_read[i]=adc_buffer[i];
08000254:   ldr     r3, [pc, #52]   ; (0x800028c <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+88>)
08000256:   ldr     r2, [r7, #12]
08000258:   lsls    r2, r2, #1
0800025a:   ldrh    r1, [r2, r3]
0800025c:   ldr     r3, [pc, #48]   ; (0x8000290 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+92>)
0800025e:   ldr     r2, [r7, #12]
08000260:   lsls    r2, r2, #1
08000262:   strh    r1, [r2, r3]
 61           for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
08000264:   ldr     r3, [r7, #12]
08000266:   adds    r3, #1
08000268:   str     r3, [r7, #12]
0800026a:   ldr     r3, [r7, #12]
0800026c:   cmp     r3, #10
0800026e:   ble.n   0x8000254 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+32>  // ends here
 97          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14,0u);
```

```
 54           HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14);
0800023c:   movs    r3, #128        ; 0x80
0800023e:   lsls    r3, r3, #7
08000240:   ldr     r2, [pc, #116]  ; (0x80002b8 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+132>)
08000242:   movs    r1, r3
08000244:   movs    r0, r2
08000246:   bl      0x8002cc6 <HAL_GPIO_TogglePin>
 70          adc_read[0]=adc_buffer[0];
0800024a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #112]  ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800024c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #0]
0800024e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #112]  ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000250:   strh    r2, [r3, #0]
 71          adc_read[1]=adc_buffer[1];
08000252:   ldr     r3, [pc, #104]  ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
08000254:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #2]
08000256:   ldr     r3, [pc, #104]  ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000258:   strh    r2, [r3, #2]
 72          adc_read[2]=adc_buffer[2];
0800025a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #96]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800025c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #4]
0800025e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #96]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000260:   strh    r2, [r3, #4]
 73          adc_read[3]=adc_buffer[3];
08000262:   ldr     r3, [pc, #88]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
08000264:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #6]
08000266:   ldr     r3, [pc, #88]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000268:   strh    r2, [r3, #6]
 74          adc_read[4]=adc_buffer[4];
0800026a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #80]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800026c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #8]
0800026e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #80]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000270:   strh    r2, [r3, #8]
 75          adc_read[5]=adc_buffer[5];
08000272:   ldr     r3, [pc, #72]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
08000274:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #10]
08000276:   ldr     r3, [pc, #72]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000278:   strh    r2, [r3, #10]
 76          adc_read[6]=adc_buffer[6];
0800027a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #64]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800027c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #12]
0800027e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #64]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000280:   strh    r2, [r3, #12]
 77          adc_read[7]=adc_buffer[7];
08000282:   ldr     r3, [pc, #56]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
08000284:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #14]
08000286:   ldr     r3, [pc, #56]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000288:   strh    r2, [r3, #14]
 78          adc_read[8]=adc_buffer[8];
0800028a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #48]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800028c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #16]
0800028e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #48]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000290:   strh    r2, [r3, #16]
 79          adc_read[9]=adc_buffer[9];
08000292:   ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
08000294:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #18]
08000296:   ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
08000298:   strh    r2, [r3, #18]
 80          adc_read[10]=adc_buffer[10];
0800029a:   ldr     r3, [pc, #32]   ; (0x80002bc <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+136>)
0800029c:   ldrh    r2, [r3, #20]
0800029e:   ldr     r3, [pc, #32]   ; (0x80002c0 <HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback+140>)
080002a0:   strh    r2, [r3, #20]
 97          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14,0u);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your compilation command. Did you let the compiler optimize for speed?

Comment: Have the compiler show the code it generates. ARM GCC 13.2 "-O3" doesn't generate much different code for `memcpy()`, `for` loops up from or down to zero.

Comment: Direct assignment (loop unrolling) will always be quicker because there is no branching involved. Not much you can do about this unless your processor has branch prediction (it doesn't). Branching is very slow as the CPU must purge the pipeline. A 3x slowdown is not unreasonable.

Comment: In terms of optimisations: 1) what is the expected size range of the array you want to copy 2) what size are the data elements (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit etc)?

Comment: *All data is int 16 bits.* There shouldn't be any need to say it. You should show a self-contained code example that we can compile to see the output.

Comment: Was that compiled with no optimisations? It looks insanely inefficient. It keeps loading the base pointers into r3 every single time it needs them.

Answer (score 11):

Speaking about performance without mentioning how you compile the code is kind of pointless. It shouldn't be a mind-blowing realization that optimized code runs faster than code with optimization disabled...

That being said, there is just so much the optimizer can do when hardware registers or DMA buffers are involved. All of these are (ought to be) `volatile` and that effectively blocks many optimizations. It could for example block function inlining, which is a common one.

In your specific example, loop unrolling would be one kind of optimization. But compilers usually follow some scheme for when it does this, like up to 8 objects or similar (likely configurable through some option). Because loop unrolling is a speed over program size optimization.

We may note that your code doesn't use `memcpy`, which is often recommended to get the fastest possible code. Modern compilers replace `memcpy` with whatever is the fastest for the given data and target. However, using `memcpy` on `volatile`-qualified data isn't well-defined, since that would involve poorly-defined behavior when "casting away" `volatile`. In theory, that could lead to all manner of unexpected bugs. So based on that, a manual loop might not be as naive as it seems.

However, hard-copying data in bare metal embedded applications is often to be avoided and replaced with pointer swaps. In situations like a buffer getting filled up from an ISR, then hard-copy is almost certainly the wrong thing to do and you should just swap pointers to buffers ("double buffering"), so that the ISR and the background program never work on the same one.

With DMA, you could re-route the DMA to use another buffer while you work the the present one. Getting DMA working is often a head ache though, so most would just take the slight performance hit and hard copy the data.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning half complete interrupts as a way to work on half the buffer while the other is updating. This should spread out the load a bit with little complexity added.

Comment: @William Yeah can be done, and that's usually how DMA works too. But swapping pointers to buffers is super easy and with no added complexity, so if one can afford some 20-100 bytes or whatever for an additional buffer, that's what I would strongly recommend.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to speed up the for loop? For my final program I'd like to add the values to a variable which is then averaged to give me a filtered output.

When in doubt, always check the compiler optimization settings and the generated assembly code.

I think the default is to optimize for size to generate the smallest code. On simple microcontrollers, this is often faster because smaller code means less instructions, which executes faster than more instructions. An exception is loops.

In this case the for() loop will be compiled into the usual: do the useful code inside, increment the counter, test for end of loop, jump back to the beginning.

When you manually unroll the loop, you keep only the useful stuff and get rid of the for() loop management, so it's faster.

If you use -02 it may decide to unroll the loop itself.

That said you do not need to copy your ADC data. I think the ADC DMA supports double buffering on this micro, so you can use that instead of copying. If you want to keep the old samples and avoid overwriting them with new ADC reads, instead of copying them out of the DMA buffer, simply change the address of the DMA buffer to write the new samples somewhere else.

If the goal is to average samples for more accuracy... STM32G0 supports that in hardware, but STM32F1 does not. So if you want maximum speed you'll just have to write

```
sum = adc_buffer[0] + adc_buffer[1] + ...
```

Note if you have many samples you don't need to unroll the whole loop. You can sum, say 8 values, and wrap that in a for() loop. This way the loop overhead will be once per 8 values instead of once per value.

Answer (score 4):

The question, as many other such question, lacks enough detail. To talk about short code benchmarks in a way that won't waste your own time first, and our time second, you should make a self-contained example on Godbolt.

Your code looks like every other non-optimized output would look. The code is meant to look very similar to the C source so that it'll be easy to debug. Optimization often makes debugging harder - but that's mostly because debuggers are somewhat braindead in their understanding of the code relative to the compiler proper, not because there's anything wrong with optimization.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {} ADC_HandleTypeDef;
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin(int, ...);
enum {GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14};

volatile int16_t adc_read[12];
volatile int16_t adc_buffer[12];

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 1u);

  for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    adc_read[i] = adc_buffer[i];
  }

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 0u);
}
```

Below is what ARM gcc 11.2.1 (none) produced with -O3 optimization level. As you can see, the loop is already unrolled, and each 16-bit value is transferred using an individual 16-bit read and write:

```
HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback:
        mov     r2, #1
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r1, r2
        mov     r0, #0
        bl      HAL_GPIO_WritePin
        ldr     r3, .L4
        ldrh    r0, [r3]
        lsl     r0, r0, #16
        asr     r0, r0, #16
        strh    r0, [r3, #24]   @ movhi
        ldrh    r0, [r3, #2]
        lsl     r0, r0, #16
        asr     r0, r0, #16
        strh    r0, [r3, #26]   @ movhi
        ldrh    r0, [r3, #4]
        lsl     r0, r0, #16
        asr     r0, r0, #16
        strh    r0, [r3, #28]   @ movhi
        ldrh    r0, [r3, #6]
        lsl     r0, r0, #16
        asr     r0, r0, #16
        strh    r0, [r3, #30]   @ movhi
        ldrh    r0, [r3, #8]
        lsl     r0, r0, #16
        asr     r0, r0, #16
        strh    r0, [r3, #32]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #10]
        mov     r2, #0
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        strh    ip, [r3, #34]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #12]
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        strh    ip, [r3, #36]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #14]
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        strh    ip, [r3, #38]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #16]
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        strh    ip, [r3, #40]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #18]
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        strh    ip, [r3, #42]   @ movhi
        ldrh    ip, [r3, #20]
        lsl     ip, ip, #16
        asr     ip, ip, #16
        mov     r1, #1
        mov     r0, r2
        strh    ip, [r3, #44]   @ movhi
        bl      HAL_GPIO_WritePin
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
```

To copy the data more efficiently, the buffers can be unions, so that copying happens 32 bits at a time, and the data is accessed 16 bits at a time:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {} ADC_HandleTypeDef;
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin(int, ...);
enum {GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14};

volatile union {
    int32_t raw[6];
    int16_t values[12];
} adc_read, adc_buffer;

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 1u);

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    adc_read.raw[i] = adc_buffer.raw[i];
  }

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 0u);
}
```

Now the output is even faster:

```
HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback:
        mov     r2, #1
        push    {r4, lr}
        mov     r1, r2
        mov     r0, #0
        bl      HAL_GPIO_WritePin
        mov     r2, #0
        ldr     r3, .L4
        ldr     r0, [r3]
        str     r0, [r3, #24]
        ldr     r0, [r3, #4]
        str     r0, [r3, #28]
        ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
        str     r0, [r3, #32]
        ldr     r0, [r3, #12]
        str     r0, [r3, #36]
        ldr     r0, [r3, #16]
        str     r0, [r3, #40]
        ldr     r0, [r3, #20]
        mov     r1, #1
        str     r0, [r3, #44]
        mov     r0, r2
        bl      HAL_GPIO_WritePin
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
```

The manually unrolled loop produces **identical** assembly output, as it should on any decent modern compiler:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) {
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 1u);

  adc_read.raw[0] = adc_buffer.raw[0];
  adc_read.raw[1] = adc_buffer.raw[1];
  adc_read.raw[2] = adc_buffer.raw[2];
  adc_read.raw[3] = adc_buffer.raw[3];
  adc_read.raw[4] = adc_buffer.raw[4];
  adc_read.raw[5] = adc_buffer.raw[5];

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, 0u);
}
```

But the whole thing is rather moot since you can use DMA for the transfer, and that will be the fastest in all cases.

There are two ways to do it with DMA:

1. Keep the interrupt handler, just transfer ADC data using DMA:

   ```
   void callback() {
     set_gpio_pin(1u);
     start_dma();
     while (!dma_complete());
     set_gpio_pin(0u);
   }
   ```

   The DMA transfer should be set up in the main thread, before any callbacks. `start_dma()` and `dma_complete()` should be very small inline functions that just manipulate the DMA control/status bits.
2. Let DMA do the whole job. You'd set up three chained transfers.

   - First transfer sets the GPIO to 1.
   - Second transfer transfers the ADC data.
   - Third transfer sets the GPIO to 0.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered test and branch is slow. You do not say which compiler you are using. If ARM GCC then optimization level 3 should automatically unroll loops that are smaller than 16 cycles. If not ARM GCC (e.g. Keil, MSVC) then there will be a directive of the form either "#pragma unroll" or "_attribute(?something?)" that can be placed just outside the loop to instruct the compiler what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 1):

When using gcc, even if one doesn't trust the optimizer, using `register` storage class can improve performance enormously.

The following code, for example:

```
unsigned arr1[8],arr2[8];
void test(void)
{
    register unsigned *p1 = arr1;
    register unsigned *p2 = arr2;
    register unsigned *pe = p1+8;
    do
    {
        *p1 += *p2;
        p1++;
        p2++;            
    } while(p1 < pe);
}
```

generates the following loop at optimization level 0:

```
.L2:
    ldr     r2, [r4]
    ldr     r3, [r5]
    add     r3, r2, r3
    str     r3, [r4]
    add     r4, r4, #4
    add     r5, r5, #4
    cmp     r4, r6
    bcc     .L2
```

Performance could be improved if the compiler could use ldrmia and strmia to eliminate the need for "add x,x,#4" instructions, but it's still massively better than without the `register` qualifier.

Comment: That's the thing though: `register` doesn't actually do anything at all in O2 and O3 IIRC. So it's nice for -O0, but otherwise useless. And `register` is effectively not a thing in C++ anyway, so you'd have to resort to implementation-specific keywords. At that point it's IMHO simplest just not to mess with -O0. There's not any reason to use it, especially not with C code that compiles super fast anyway.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: At higher optimization settings, gcc requires memory barriers to ensure reliably correct semantics for many constructs.  Commercial compiler developers are wise enough to recognize that a volatile-qualified write might disturb the value of "ordinary" objects, but the authors of gcc (and clang) would view code that usefully refrains from register-caching objects across volatile writes as "less efficient" than useless code that would use stale values in the absence of a compiler-specific memory barrier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up pointers to the start of each array.
2. Count the for loop index variable down to zero.
3. In the loop, copy the values using the pointers, auto-post-increment them both.

This reduces per-loop operations. But a sensible compiler optimising setting would likely produce similar code from your [i] original !